# Rails3 routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, nested-routes

My scenario: Movies have reviews, reviews have comments.

Movie model:

```
has_many :reviews
```

Review model:

```
has_many :comments
belongs_to :movie
```

Comment model:

```
belongs_to :review
```

Routes:

```
resources :movies do
  resources :reviews do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Comments controller:

```
def create
  @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
  @review = Review.where(:movie_id => @movie.id)
  @comment = @review.comments.create(params[:comment])  // Line 5
  redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
end
```

Comment view:

```
<%= form_for([@movie, r, r.comments.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The error that I get is:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `comments' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007ff5c5870010>):
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:5:in `create'
```

Can somebody please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Review.where` returns a list of reviews, what you want is an instance

```
@review = Review.where(:movie_id => @movie.id).first
```

or

```
@review = Review.find_by_movie_id(@movie.id)
```

Make sure to handle `nil` case.

Comment: works perfect.. (i just accepted an answer for another question and it asks me to wait for 4mins).. will accept it after 4.. thanks a lot